# Is this an abbreviated or a participial construction?

Tags: grammar

> "Some say he died. Codswallop, in my opinion. Dunno if
>   he had enough human left in him to die. Some say he's still out there,
>   bidin' his time, like, but I don' believe it. People who was on his
>   side came back ter ours. Some of 'em came outta kinda trances. Don’
>   reckon they could've done if he was comin' back. 
>      
>   "Most of us reckon *he's* still out there somewhere but **lost his
>   powers**. Too weak to carry on. 'Cause somethin' about you finished
>   him, Harry. There was somethin' goin' on that night he hadn't counted
>   on –– I dunno what it was, no one does –– but somethin' about you
>   stumped him, all right." 
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is lost a past participle sharing *he’s*, or is the phrase a participial construction?

Comment: Yeah, the *he's* is implied to refer to both. "(he's) still out there but (he's) lost his powers."

Comment: Why is this downvote? This site is for EFL learners. Even if the question is easy, it should not be downvoted.

Comment: Note that in *he's still out there somewhere*, the *'s* stands for *is*, but in *(he's) lost his powers*, the *'s* stands for *has*. I don't believe that this would be deemed grammatical by purists (but this is Hagrid speaking ...).

Comment: Well, you can also read it as *is* coordinated with *lost*, possibly with a (nonstandard) omitted auxiliary, so I don't think the coordination is necessarily ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this sentence:

> Most of us reckon he's still out there somewhere but **lost his powers**.

You could also re-write it as:

> Most of us reckon (he's) still out there somewhere but (he's) lost his powers.

This is using a loose interpretation of the contraction (he's) to mean either (he is) or (he has).  So it could again be rewritten thusly:

> Most of us reckon (he is) still out there somewhere but (he has) lost his powers.

As noted, Hagrid is not known for his strict adherence to grammatical norms.  :)